# JAX-RS @CookieParam Ionic client not sending cookies (Capacitor)

Tags: java, ionic-framework, cookies, jax-rs, angular-httpclient

I'm sending a cookie as parameter in headers with the annotation @CookieParam.

First step : `register/start`

```
    @GET
    @Path("/start")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @NoCache
    public Response start() {
        try {
            String myIdentifier = "abcdefghijkl123456789";

            LOGGER.info(String.format("My identifier: %s ", myIdentifier)); 

            // the identifier is send through the cookies in headers
            NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie("myIdentifierCookie", myIdentifier, null, null, null,
                    1200, false, false);
            return Response.ok().cookie(cookie).build();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }
    }
```

From now it's good. When I do the GET, I can read my cookie on Response Headers.
Now I'm doing a POST method, to check the email received, that has `@CookieParam` annotation.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/email")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @NoCache
    public Response emailCheck(@CookieParam("myIdentifierCookie") Cookie identifierCookie,
                                  CheckEmailRequest request) {

        String identifier = "";
        try {
            identifier = identifierCookie.getValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception e ", e);
            LOGGER.error(String.format("Invalid  request identifier: %s ", identifier));
            return Response.status(500).build();
        }
    }
```

And my cookie value is empty and I'm receiving :

```
(executor-thread-62) exception e : java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:151)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.lambda$invoke$3(MethodInjectorImpl.java:122)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyNow(CompletableFuture.java:680)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:658)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:2158)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:122)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:594)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:468)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:421)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:423)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invoke$1(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1183)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2299)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:477)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:252)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:156)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:238)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:120)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:36)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:85)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:224)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1426)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

Is my implementation wrong?
Thank you very much.

**EDIT : @Paul Samsotha**

Which client am I using?

I'm using `Ionic with Angular`, and my plugin is the angular Http module from `@angular/common/http`.
I have a `backend service` defined like that :

```
  get(url, options?): Observable<any> {
    options = { ...options, withCredentials: true };
    return this.http.get(myURL, options);
  }

  post(url, body, options?): Observable<any> {
    options = { ...options, withCredentials: true };
    return this.http.post(myURL, body, options);
  }
```

So on my component i'm using it like this :

```
  public getRegistrationStart() {
    return this.backendService.get('/register/start', {
      observe: 'response',
    });
  }

  public emailStep(email) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.backendService.postPublic('/register/email', email, {
      observe: 'response',
      headers,
    });
  }
```

My email is send as a JSON like `{"email":"test@test.test"}`

**EDIT 2 : @Paul**

Here a screen of my start request, the server responds with a Set-Cookie containing my cookie (I've set up a random number generator), but my cookie is here.

[image]

Comment: What client are you using? And possible can you show how you're making the requests.

Comment: I'm using Angular Ionic, and especially the Angular HTTP Client from ```@angular/common/http```.
I'm editing my post to show you my requests.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause but did you set the cors access-control-allow-credentials response header? Also have you inspected the request from the front end to see if the cookie is sent? You can see a lot of what is going on if you use the browser dev tools. Run ionic on the browser so you can use these tools

Comment: I'm using Quarkus, in my ```application.properties```, I'm setting a parameter ```quarkus.http.cors=true```,  if I remove this parameter, my calls don't work anymore. https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference
I've also tried with the header you mentionned, but the problem occurs directly when calling the ```cookie.getValue()``` method. That's the first thing I'm trying to log, and it's always null.
But when I do my ```start``` method, I can read the cookie in my browser

Comment: The only reason it could be on the server is because the client is not sending it. Yea the cookie can be stored in the browser but that doesn’t mean it is being sent back to the server. This is what I am asking you to check. You can check the network tab In the dev tools and see the headers in the request. There should be a Cookie header if it is being sent back to the server. If it’s not being sent, then we need to figure out why.

Comment: I meant to say “the only reason it could be _NULL_”

Comment: You're right, my cookie doesn't show on my email request. Only on the ```start``` request. Is there any reason for that? I'm doing ```return Response.ok().cookie(cookie).build();``` on the ```start``` method, and ```@CookieParam``` on the ```email```. Is my implementation wrong at this level?

Comment: If I log the cookie param on my ```email``` method, it returns ```null```
So now I understand that my problem comes from the CookieParam, it should has a value but it's null

Comment: I think you’re looking at it wrong. So the server sends the cookie and the client is supposed to send it back along with the request. But it is not sending it back. So that’s the question you have to answer. Try to google “ionic not sending cookie back to server” and see if anything helps. It’s been a while since I’ve used ionic so I’m not sure.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. When the client sends the first request, the server sends a cookie along with the response. This cookie is what identifies the client. The client is supposed to send that cookie back to the server with each request so the server knows who is making the request. The @CookieParam is the cookie that the client sends back to the server. It should be the same one the server sent to the client on the first request. But in your case, the client is not sending the cookie back. That’s the problem you need to solve.

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much for your help Sir, I think my problem is dealing with SameSite. But you're right, my problem is Ionic and the way my cookies are blocked. I'm going to search and i'll bring a response. 
Again, thank you

Comment: When the server initially sends the cookie to the client, it is send in the form of a Set-Cookie response header. When the client sends it back, it is sent in the form of a Cookie request header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was not JAX RS but Ionic Capacitor which blocked cookies. Problem solved by adding this line in `capacitor.config.json` :

```
"server":{"hostname":"mydomain"}
```

Cookie was not intercepted in Android, it was intercepted in iOS, so adding this line in the `capacitor.config.json` only in the iOS build file solved my problem.

Huge thanks to Paul Samsotha who showed me the path to the solution.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Did you use the search terms I suggested? Is that how you found the solution?

Comment: Yes, i've search with your exact terms on Google, and I found this topic : https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1143
That solved my problem ! Now, cookies are send Android and iOS. Amazing !

Comment: That's awesome. Just keep in mind though that it is just a workaround. If won't work if you need to call some third-party APIs. You would have to make the calls through your server as a gateway to the thrid-party API